# Xamarin Android GoogleApi get image from returned URI

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-api

Using the Google Api Client in my Xamarin.Android project, when i retrieve the *url* of the user's image/profile picture, it looks something like this :

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDmooDF92bZY2HXfW9Q9MiA23C9AB4AFpZtbmCz
```

Setting this as the source of an `ImageView` via the `setImageUri` property results in nothing, however, i do get a warning in the *build output* window as follows :

> No content provider: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDmooDF92bZY2HXfW9Q9MiA23C9AB4AFpZtbmCz

So, how am i supposed to get this to work? If i have to download the image from the uri, then *how would i do that* as the uri doesn't point to any physical file(image).

Comment: SetImageUri does not retrieve images from remote sources, it is designed to load local resources (file, assets, resources). That link you provided does link to a http resource, you can http get it and save the binary return in a local file (assumably 
in your app's cache dir and apply that local file:/// reference to your ImageView

Comment: @SushiHangoverm any directions on how do i download that image ?

Comment: You can do it yourself via `HttpClient` (lots of SOs related to this). Or use a 3rd-party library like `Square.Picasso` that can cache it and directly link it to an ImageView for for you  (it is java based but C# binding projects exist via Nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Square+Picasso)